# Turn array of hashes into an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When using Objects returned by the ActiveRecord collection proxy, using a loop if fine in a view, but sometimes I want to turn just one of the hash' common attributes into an array. I find I'm doing it a lot, which results in what appears to be somewhat verbose:

```
 forum_roles = []

 @forum #=> [{id: 0, name: 'a'},{id: 1, name: 'b'}]

 @forum.each do |role|
    forum_roles << role.name
 end

 forum_roles #=> ['a','b']
```

Just wondering if there's an easier way to arriving at `['a','b']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Array#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-map) when you have an array of hashes

```
forum_roles = @forum.map { |role| role[:name] }
forum_roles # ['a','b']
```

UPDATE:

With ActiveRecord Objects, there's a shorcut as @vee commented

```
@forum.map(&:name)
```

If you have an ActiveRecord Relation and you only want an array of a column, use [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)

```
@forum.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: @vee `&:name` isn't correct. That invokes `role.name()` on each hash, not `role[:name]`. That would work for an array of objects, but not an array of hashes.

Comment: @meagar, but `@forum` is an AR Relation, so isn't it safe to assume `name` is an attribute of presumably `Role` object?

Comment: @meagar the title of the question is misleading.  reading the body will tell us that `@forum` is indeed an AR relation which is why the OP can do `forum_roles << role.name`

Comment: Wow, `pluck` is plucking amazing.